# Rejection Region for Paired Sign Test

Tags: self-study, sign-test

I'm taking an online stats course and I'm stuck on understanding a part of the textbook.

It's in regards to the rejection region for the non-parametric sign test for a paired experiment.

My book says, for a two-tailed test $H_a$: $p$ is not equal to 0.5. Reject $H_0$ if $x \le x_L$, or $x \ge x_U$, where $P(x \le x_L) \le a/2$ and $P(x \ge x_U) \le a/2$.

In an example in the textbook, where $x = 6$ and $a = 0.05$, they find the p-value and conclude that because the p-value is larger than 0.10, they cannot reject Ho.

I'm not sure if I'm understanding.. for these types of problems, can I always reject $H_0$ if the $p$-value I find is less than (or equal to) $2a$?

Also, how do I find $x_L$ and $x_U$? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's in regards to the rejection region for the non-parametric sign test for a paired experiment.

Keep in mind (though I guess you're aware of this) that once you take the signs of the differences, it is a one sample test on those signs.

> I'm not sure if I'm understanding.. for these types of problems, can I always reject H0 if the p-value I find is less than (or equal to) 2a

You reject if the two-tailed p-value is less than $\alpha$ (i.e. $2\times \alpha/2$), not $2\alpha$.

> Also, how do I find $x_L$ and $x_U$?

It depends on what resources you have. Are you working from tables? How are those tables organized, exactly?

You need to determine the quantiles that have as close as possible to a probability of $\alpha/2$ equal to or beyond them (i.e away from p=$\frac12$ toward the tails), *without going over*. Then the lower one is $x_L$ and the upper one is $x_U$.

Consider 8 pairs, for example, with $\alpha = 0.10$. The probabilities (from the binomial distribution) of the number of positive signs is:

```
n+      0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8  
prob 0.00391 0.03125 0.10938 0.21875 0.27344 0.21875 0.10938 0.03125 0.00391
```

Here $\alpha/2$ is $0.05$. Let's go in from the bottom end to find $x_L$.

If $x_L$ were 0, we'd have $\alpha/2=0.00391$ which is way below $0.05$. Now try $x_L=1$ -- now the proportion at or below $x_L$ is 0.00391+0.03125 = 0.03516 which is still below 0.05. But if we try $x_L=2$ the sum of the terms is above $\alpha/2$ so $x_L$ must be $1$ here. Similarly working from the top end (or using the symmetry about $4$), $x_U$ in this example would be $7$.

Note that because the distribution is discrete we don't actually have $\alpha$ at $0.10$, it's (almost) always smaller*. In this particular case the true significance level is $0.0703$.

* unless you're one of those people that actually randomizes tests in practice, but I expect that's not been mentioned in your book.